# Salesforce Integrations best practice

Tags: apex, rest-api, webservices, certification

I need to implement a request that will be sent over a 3rd party (used as tunnel) to SAP.

Which mean -

**Request:**

SF **-->** Server 3rd Party **-->** SAP

**Response:**

SF **<--** Server 3ed Party **<--** SAP

The integration should use REST API via POST method - and send and receive a JSON.

I want to know my options for this Integration (  SF **-->** Server 3rd Party and vice versa ) and what is the best practice to use them.

I checked some and some I'll be thankful for more information.

1. Auth with IP - Not really an option - SF has more than 1M IPs to whitelist in the 3rd party server.
2. Send an encrypted Text via header with the AES algorithm. The symmetric key will be share manually with the 3rd party server.
3. Certification - Which I don't know much about it - Just the case that the 3rd Party should create and give me the detail about the cert - that later should be inserted into SF.

another better way?

About option 3 -> There are more to know except from define it in SF certification and use it in the method : `req.setClientCertificateName('name_Of_the_Cert');`

What is the best to use, what is not recommended? and when should I decide to close a connection and open it again by the 3rd party server - which means the difference between sync callouts and async callouts between servers.

example -

when I will want to wait and use the data that returned from the 3rd party server and when I will want to close the connection and wait for the 3rd party server to make a request to me with the Data.

Thanks!

Comment: have you looked already at salesforce connected apps and oauth to connect from middleware to salesforce?

Comment: Yes but as you said - Connect from middleware to salesforce.
I'm the one who created the request... which means I need to create the other way - Salesforce to middleware. So I dont think it can help me here

Comment: so your scenario is basically apex callouts to an external api(middleware) where authentication is done with named credentials https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_named_credentials.htm